# Trouble Creating a connection in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am using Fedora 18 and recently installed MySQL workbench.
I created a new connection in MySQL workbench, but when trying to open I get the following error:

Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Please:

1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Any idea what the issue would be?

Comment: Are you running MyQSL workbench on the same machine as the MySQL server?

Comment: Yeah both running on localhost

Comment: Have you followed the steps suggested by the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 18 is a Linux Based Operating System and it works on chmod 777. so there should be authentication problem. otherwise server 127.0.0.1 and host name , username same as we keep in windows. you need to set authentication.